# Property is not working for get a value from another form

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a Windows form application for Serial Port. I have different forms in my application. So my write value of sensor data is shown in the different form. What I have to do is when I change the value of write data of sensor it will have to change the value of the sensor. I tried that in the same form it works. but when I try another form it shows this exception:

> System.FormatException: 'The input string format is incorrect.'

I tried to do with using property. My code is below:

In config form, I created a property and call in button in the same form

```
public partial class config : Form
{
        public string _txtRsltDensity
        {
            get { return txtRsltDensity.Text; }
            set { txtRsltDensity.Text = value; }
        }
        private void btnRsltDensity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1 f1 = new Form1();
            int val = Convert.ToInt32(_txtRsltDensity);
            bool res = Int32.TryParse(_txtRsltDensity, out val);
            if (res == true && val > -1 && val < 2)
            {
                f1.Density();// this is function created in main form
            }
        }
}
```

---

In the main form first I created a command for sensor and then I created a function to write the new value in the sensor

```
 public string cmdMake(int cmd, int rw)
 {
        int cmdLen = 0;
        string param = "";
        string strCmd = "D";
        AsciiCode ascCode = new AsciiCode();
        strCmd = strCmd + Convert.ToInt32(numSlave.Value).ToString("X2");
        if (rw == CMD_RD)             {
            strCmd = strCmd + "07" + cmd.ToString("X2");
            strCmd = strCmd + dterr_chk.CalCRC16(strCmd);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (cmd)
            {
                case 13:
                    config C = new config();
                    param = dtConv.DblToStr(double.Parse(C.txtRsltDensity.Text), 0, 2, 0);// here show the exception may be because the value of textbox is zero  
                    break;
            }
            cmdLen = 7 + param.Length;
            strCmd = strCmd + cmdLen.ToString("X2") + cmd.ToString("X2") + param;
            strCmd = strCmd + dterr_chk.CalCRC16(strCmd);
        }
        strCmd = strCmd + ascCode.STR_CRLF;
        return (strCmd);
    }
```

Comment: You never call `C.ShowDialog();`, so the user never has the opportunity to fill in that value. If you're showing an instance of `config` elsewhere, it is a _different_ instance (in the way that two people can own the same model of car, but each car is unique).

Comment: To clarify my comment: An empty textbox's value (String.Empty) will cause `NUMBERTYPE.Parse(textboxValue)` to throw this exception because an empty string is not an empty value, nor is it 0.

Comment: @john thank you for your reply. I don't need to call C.ShowDialog(); because when I insert new value in config form it will have to change the data of sensor. value of textbox is not coming from config form I tried with delegate also but it was not worked

Comment: But you're creating a new instance of it? Does the constructor of `config` populate _txtRsltDensity with a sensor value?

Comment: @john No how can I do that can you help to for this please

Comment: How is `_txtRsltDensity` ever going to have a value then? You never show it, so the user can't enter it, and you have no code to populate it from the constructor of `config`.

Comment: but in Density() I did this
   public void Density()
        {
            int addr = 13;
            int cmdNo = 05;
            ParamWrite(addr, true);

            if (sp1.RsTransmitRec(cmdMake(cmdNo, CMD_RD)) == true)             {
                if (DivRecData(sp1.GetRecData, cmdNo) == true)                  {
                   Con._txtRsltDensity = RecDt.ConfDensity.ToString();
                }
                           }
        }

Comment: But you're creating a new instance of config here: `config C = new config();`. It's like buying a car, making modifications, you then go to the showroom and buy an identical model to the one you bought. You can't expect the new car to have the modifications the old one did because it's a different car.

Comment: @john Thank you john I got it now its solved

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. Imagine this is your main form:

```
private Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    config c = new config();
    c.Show();
}

private string cmdMake(int cmd, int rw)
{
    config c = new config();
    double val = double.Parse(c.Property);
}
```

You have two instances of config. For the sake of an analogy: you have two cars of the same make and model, but they are different cars. Any changes to one will not be effected in the other because they are *different* cars.

You can move config into your main form's scope, which will net you a single instance of `config`:

```
public class MainForm : MainForm
{
    config c = new config();

    private Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c.Show();
    }

    private string cmdMake(int cmd, int rw)
    {
        double val = double.Parse(c.Property);
    }
}
```

Now, the parse could be a problem. You should instead use `TryParse` - if the number is invalid it will return `false` rather than throwing an exception.

You can use it like this:

```
dobule val;
if (!double.TryParse(c.Property, out val))
{
    // parsing c.Property failed. do something to handle it
}
```